# How can i retrieve table count in a database by using eloquent in Laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

Please am trying to display student count from my database into the H3 Tag( The Number of rows ) in my **dashboard.blade.php**. I want to display the number of students in the database when the dashboard opens. i have tried my very best but it isn't working out for me. I need help.  Below is what i have done so far. Thanks

```
<span>
<img src="{{ asset('images/studentIcon.png') }}" style="width: 70px; height: 70px; border-radius: 50%">
      <h3 style="color: red">  echo $displaycount </h3>
      <p class="cardtext">Registered Students</p>
</span>
```

This my route

```
Route::get('/dashboard', 'StudentRegister@getCount');
```

**StudentRegister.php** controller file
Model File Name is **Student**

```
        public function getCount(){

        $nStudents = Student::where 1;
        $displaycount = $nStudents->count();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a syntax error , can you try this one :

```
$nStudents = Student::where('id', '<=', $correctedComparisons)->count();
```

Or (in case you don't have any condition to filter about)

```
 $count = Student::count();
```

Comment: Am now seeing a blank page in my dashboard page, how do I display the result in the H3 tag

Comment: check what inside **$displaycount**

Comment: I think the problem now is with the route.. The count is displaying on a blank page instead of the H3 tag

Comment: Yes please, I have

Comment: My problem now is to return view to the H3 tag

Comment: you have to render the variabe to the template like : 

   **return view('index', ['displaycount' => '$displaycount']);**

Comment: Thanks alot. Have been able to fix it